# Intellij IDEA: "Cannot find declaration to go to" - message in a new javascript project

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I'm getting "Cannot find declaration to go to in" message when try to Ctrl + click the path of an imported module

This message shows up if the path contains "@" symbol as a root reference.

This is happening in my new project and there is no such problem in the old project.

How to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: `@` is likely a path alias; where do you have it defined?

Comment: @lena I haven't defined it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

---

First of all  invalidate cashes: menu `File` -> `Invalidate Caches`
[image]

---

After that set webpack settings
[image]

according to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-webpack.html#edit_webpack_configuration_file

---

And also mark \src\ dir as a sources root directory
[image: And also mark \src\ dir as a sources root directory]

---

upd:
And also make sure that value of property "settings.editor.selected.configurable" = "preferences.pluginManager" in file /.idea/workspace.xml :

```
<component name="PropertiesComponent">
    ...
    <property name="settings.editor.selected.configurable" value="preferences.pluginManager" />
    ...
</component>
```

upd: not sure about this step...